# Duplicated rows when aggregating data in dplyr()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a set of cross-linguistic data by joining three datasets together in dplyr(). Two of the datasets are 'dictionaries' of sorts - they are word lists that I want to attach to speakers. There are 15 speakers and so a number of repetitions throughout the data, while each word only appears once in each of the dictionaries.

When I join two using left_join(), I get replicated cells. I know I can remove the duplicated cells, but I sense that there must be something simple that I'm doing wrong to create this issue.

Example data is as follows:

```
 French <- c("un", "deux", "trois", "chien")
 English <- c("one", "two", "three", "dog")
 type <- c("number", "number", "number", "animal")
 speaker <- c(1, 1, 1, 4)

 df.fr = data.frame(speaker, French)
 df.en = data.frame(speaker, English)
 df.type = data.frame(English, type)
```

I want to create a new dataset, `new.df`, by joining `df.en` and `df.fr` by `speaker`, and then joining that to `df.type` by `English`.

Preferably I would use dplyr() to do this. When I do the following, I get duplicated rows:

```
 new.data <- df.fr %>% left_join(df.en)
```

which generates

```
    speaker French English
 1        1     un     one
 2        1     un     two
 3        1     un   three
 4        1   deux     one
 5        1   deux     two
 6        1   deux   three
 7        1  trois     one
 8        1  trois     two
 9        1  trois   three
 10       4  chien     dog
```

When really I just want it to join 'un' to 'one', 'deux' to 'two', etc:

```
   speaker French English   type
 1       1     un     one number
 2       1   deux     two number
 3       1  trois   three number
 4       4  chien     dog animal
```

Comment: If these are already ordered and have the same number of elements for each 'speaker', why not just `cbind` or `dplyr::bind_cols` i.e. `bind_cols(df.fr, df.en[-1], df.type[-1])`

Comment: Unfortunately they're not ordered - I should have stated that, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from `cbind`ing the three datasets, you can create a unique `id` for each `speaker` for both `df.fr` and `df.en` and join on `speaker` + `id`:

```
library(dplyr)

df.fr %>%
  group_by(speaker) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(df.en %>% group_by(speaker) %>% mutate(id = 1:n()),
            by = c("speaker", "id")) %>%
  left_join(df.type) %>%
  select(-id)
```

If you have more than two language datasets, you can also write a more general solution using `map` and `reduce` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

list(df.fr, df.en) %>%
  map(~ group_by(., speaker) %>% mutate(id = 1:n())) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = c("speaker", "id")) %>%
  left_join(df.type) %>%
  select(-id)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   speaker [2]
  speaker French English   type
    <dbl> <fctr>  <fctr> <fctr>
1       1     un     one number
2       1   deux     two number
3       1  trois   three number
4       4  chien     dog animal
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does work - I thought the purrr option had solved the problem, but I see that there are still duplicates in the data. Perhaps I haven't explained clearly enough: the dataframes are different sizes, and there are multiple tokens of a single word in the `speaker` data, but only one instance of each word in the language datasets. So when I use the option you suggest I end up with empty cells, which I don't want.

Comment: @CatherineLaing In that case, provide a sample dataset that reflects this issue that you're seeing. My solution solves your problem with the sample dataset currently posted